# Use RDD to map dataframe rows into custom objects pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to convert each row of my dataframe into to a Python class object called Fruit.

I have a dataframe df with the following columns: `Identifier, Name, Quantity`

I also have a dictionary `fruit_color` that looks like this:
`fruit_color = {"Apple":"Red", "Lemon": "yellow", ...}`

`class Fruit(name: str, quantity: int, color: str, entryPointer: DataFrameEntry)`

I also have an object called DataFrameEntry that takes as parameters a dataframe and an identifier.

`class DataFrameEntry(df: DataFrame, index: int)`

Now I am trying to convert each row of the dataframe "df" to this object using rdds and ultimately get a list of all fruits through this piece of code:

```
df.rdd.map(lambda x: Fruit(
            x.__getitem__('Name'),
            x.__getitem__('Quantity'),
            fruit_color[x.__getitem__('Name')],
            LogEntryPointer(original_df, trigger.__getitem__('StartMarker_Index')))).collect()
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o55.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
```

Maybe my approch is wrong? How can I generally convert each row of a dataframe to a specific object in pyspark?

Thank you a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure all objects, classes you're using inside `map` is defined **inside** `map`. To be more clear, RDD's `map` will distribute workload across multiple workers (different machines), and those machines don't know what `Fruit` is.